# Exiting the child process after os.fork()

Tags: python, fork

Which is the correct function to call to exit the child process after `os.fork()`?

The documentation for `os._exit()` [states](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os._exit):

> The standard way to exit is `sys.exit(n)`.
>
> `_exit()` should normally only be used in the child process after a `fork()`.

It does not say whether it's acceptable to terminate the child process using `sys.exit()`. So:

1. Is it?
2. Are there any potential side effects of doing so?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[The unix way](http://www.unixguide.net/unix/programming/1.1.3.shtml) is that if you are a child of a `fork` then you call [_exit](http://linux.die.net/man/2/_exit).  The main difference between [exit](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exit) and `_exit` is that `exit` tidies up more - calls the `atexit` handlers, flushes `stdio` etc, whereas `_exit` does the minimum amount of stuff in userspace, just getting the kernel to close all its files etc.

This translates pretty directly into the python world with `sys.exit` doing what `exit` does and doing more of the python interpreter shutdown, where `os._exit` does the minimum possible.

If you are a child of `fork` and you call `exit` rather than `_exit` then you may end up calling exit handlers that the parent will call again when it exits causing undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the documentation on `os._exit(n)` you did not cite is

> Exit the process with status n, without calling cleanup handlers, flushing stdio buffers, etc.

So, how I'm reading this, you should use `os._exit()` as long as you share file handlers (so they will be close()'d by another process and you take care of flushing the buffers yourself (if it matters in your case). Without **shared** resources (like in "files") - it doesn't matter.

So if your child processes are computation-only, and are fed raw data (not resource handlers), then it's safe to use `exit()`.